# C# Image to base64

Tags: c#, image, base64

I have a base64 image and i have to convert it into Image. I am doing this using this code:

```
public static Image ConvertBase64StringToImage(string imageBase64String)
{
    var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
    var imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    imageStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true);
    return image;
}
```

Then i have to convert this Image into base64 again. Im using this code:

```
public static string ConvertImageToBase64String(Image image)
    {
        var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        imageStream.Position = 0;
        var imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
```

After converting the original base64Image to image and again to base64, it loses quality.The Original base64 image is 1676 in length and after conversion it has 1660 in length.

I need the same image after conversion because i have to compare it. Any ideas how to do it without losing quality?

Comment: Those 16 bytes lost are probably just padding in the original file.  Does the image look the same?  Try using a different image, does the file size change on all images, or just that one.

Comment: Image looks the same but i can't compare those images because of those 16 bytes. This problem occured for every image that i tested.

Comment: Those 16 bytes are so little data it seems unlikely that the image loses actual quality (also, this depends on the encoding / compression techniques used)

Comment: On my answer you will find the solution

Comment: Dispose the stream with: `using var imageStream = new MemoryStream();` (not related to your problem).

Answer (score 0):

According to  [this page](https://www.howtogeek.com/203979/is-the-png-format-lossless-since-it-has-a-compression-parameter/) although PNG files are lossless, you can specify how much file compression to use when storing.  IMO, as long as the `Image` comes out the same (you can compare them using some sort of MD5 tool), it doesn't matter if the size of the file is different when you save it, as the actual image is still the same as the original.

Comment: I have to check this image using base64 string, so i need to have the same size of images.

Comment: Checking the base64 of the whole file to confirm the images are the same is not the same as comparing just the images.  Imagine that a PNG file has the date it was created in some meta-data within the file.  Every time the file is saved, it is slightly different, but the image is identical.

Comment: .Net's png handling is terribly unoptimised and will almost always result in larger images than the loaded file if that file was created with some other application. Also, while it is technically possible to specify save settings with a compression level property in the .Net framework (just like it's done for jpeg), this value is actually completely unused.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to convert and compare your images, if the result from CompareImages is zero, it means that they are equal or very similar.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap("Koala.jpg");
        string img64Bit = ConvertImageToBase64String(img);
        Image newImg = ConvertBase64StringToImage(img64Bit);
        newImg.Save("KoalaCopy.jpg");
        Console.WriteLine(CompareImages(img, newImg));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ConvertImageToBase64String(Image image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static Image ConvertBase64StringToImage(string image64Bit)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image64Bit);            
        return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
    }

    public static int CompareImages(Image i1, Image i2)
    {
        string img1 = ConvertImageToBase64String(i1);
        string img2 = ConvertImageToBase64String(i2);
        return String.Compare(img1, img2);
    }
```

Comment: using `RawFormat` will make the resulting text a lot larger than it hs to be, though. You could use that for comparison, but then it's still a lot more efficient to just compare the bytes with `SequenceEquals(...)`.